# VBA Button Sets the Value of Cells But Additional Macro Doesn't Run Properly

Tags: vba, button

I have buttons that will set the value of a range of cells to a checkmark that is found in another cell. Then using Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range) another macro should run as the check marks are found in the column that the worksheet_change macro is found in. It's only working for the first row in the range. If the individual cells are changed manually by user input (drop down that references the same cell containing the check mark) then the macro runs just fine. I know that it will work without the buttons, but there's a lot of cells to ask each user to select each one manually.

Code for one of the buttons:

```
Private s As Integer
Sub Button1_Click()
    If s = 0 Then
        Range("F5,F6:F14").Value = Range("ZZ2").Value
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 1")).Select
        Selection.Characters.Text = "Uncheck All"
        s = 1

    ElseIf s = 1 Then
        Range("F5,F6:F14").Value = Range("ZZ1").Value
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 1")).Select
        Selection.Characters.Text = "Check All"
        s = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Then the code for the change in the column:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$F$5" Then
        If Range("$G$5") = True Then
            If Range("I1").Value >= Range("H5").Value Then
                Range("I5").Formula = "=$E5"
            End If

            If Range("J1").Value >= Range("H5").Value Then
                Range("J5").Formula = "=$E5"
            End If

            If Range("K1").Value >= Range("H5").Value Then
                Range("K5").Formula = "=$E5"
            End If

            If Range("L1").Value >= Range("H5").Value Then
                Range("L5").Formula = "=$E5"
            End If

            If Range("M1").Value >= Range("H5").Value Then
                Range("M5").Formula = "=$E5"
            End If

            If Range("N1").Value >= Range("H5").Value Then
                Range("N5").Formula = "=$E5"
            End If

            If Range("O1").Value >= Range("H5").Value Then
                Range("O5").Formula = "=$E5"
            End If

            If Range("P1").Value >= Range("H5").Value Then
                Range("P5").Formula = "=$E5"
            End If

            If Range("Q1").Value >= Range("H5").Value Then
                Range("Q5").Formula = "=$E5"
            End If

            If Range("R1").Value >= Range("H5").Value Then
                Range("R5").Formula = "=$E5"
            End If

            If Range("S1").Value >= Range("H5").Value Then
                Range("S5").Formula = "=$E5"
            End If

            If Range("T1").Value >= Range("H5").Value Then
                Range("T5").Formula = "=$E5"
            End If

        ElseIf Range("G5") = False Then
            Range("I5").Value = "=AF16"
            Range("J5").Value = "=AG16"
            Range("K5").Value = "=AH16"
            Range("L5").Value = "=AI16"
            Range("M5").Value = "=AJ16"
            Range("N5").Value = "=AK16"
            Range("O5").Value = "=AL16"
            Range("P5").Value = "=AM16"
            Range("Q5").Value = "=AN16"
            Range("R5").Value = "=AO16"
            Range("S5").Value = "=AP16"
            Range("T5").Value = "=AQ16"
        End If
    End If
    If Target.Column = 6 And Target.Row > 5 Then
        ThisRow = Target.Row
        Dim LValue As String
        LValue = "=E" & ThisRow
        If Range("G" & ThisRow) = True Then
            If Range("I1").Value >= Range("H" & ThisRow).Value Then
                Range("I" & ThisRow).Formula = LValue
            End If

            If Range("J1").Value >= Range("H" & ThisRow).Value Then
                Range("J" & ThisRow).Formula = LValue
            End If


            If Range("K1").Value >= Range("H" & ThisRow).Value Then
                Range("K" & ThisRow).Formula = LValue
            End If

            If Range("L1").Value >= Range("H" & ThisRow).Value Then
                Range("L" & ThisRow).Formula = LValue
            End If

            If Range("M1").Value >= Range("H" & ThisRow).Value Then
                Range("M" & ThisRow).Formula = LValue
            End If

            If Range("N1").Value >= Range("H" & ThisRow).Value Then
                Range("N" & ThisRow).Formula = LValue
            End If

            If Range("O1").Value >= Range("H" & ThisRow).Value Then
                Range("O" & ThisRow).Formula = LValue
            End If

            If Range("P1").Value >= Range("H" & ThisRow).Value Then
                Range("P" & ThisRow).Formula = LValue
            End If

            If Range("Q1").Value >= Range("H" & ThisRow).Value Then
                Range("Q" & ThisRow).Formula = LValue
            End If

            If Range("R1").Value >= Range("H" & ThisRow).Value Then
                Range("R" & ThisRow).Formula = LValue
            End If

            If Range("S1").Value >= Range("H" & ThisRow).Value Then
                Range("S" & ThisRow).Formula = LValue
            End If

            If Range("T1").Value >= Range("H" & ThisRow).Value Then
                Range("T" & ThisRow).Formula = LValue
            End If

        ElseIf Range("G" & ThisRow) = False Then
            Range("I" & ThisRow).Value = ""
            Range("J" & ThisRow).Value = ""
            Range("K" & ThisRow).Value = ""
            Range("L" & ThisRow).Value = ""
            Range("M" & ThisRow).Value = ""
            Range("N" & ThisRow).Value = ""
            Range("O" & ThisRow).Value = ""
            Range("P" & ThisRow).Value = ""
            Range("Q" & ThisRow).Value = ""
            Range("R" & ThisRow).Value = ""
            Range("S" & ThisRow).Value = ""
            Range("T" & ThisRow).Value = ""

        End If
    End If

    If Target.Column = 29 Then
        ThatRow = Target.Row
        Dim MValue As String
        MValue = "=AX" & ThatRow
        If Range("AD" & ThatRow) = True Then
            If Range("I1").Value >= Range("AE" & ThatRow).Value Then
                Range("AF" & ThatRow).Formula = MValue
            End If

            If Range("J1").Value >= Range("AE" & ThatRow).Value Then
                Range("AG" & ThatRow).Formula = MValue
            End If


            If Range("K1").Value >= Range("AE" & ThatRow).Value Then
                Range("AH" & ThatRow).Formula = MValue
            End If

            If Range("L1").Value >= Range("AE" & ThatRow).Value Then
                Range("AI" & ThatRow).Formula = MValue
            End If

            If Range("M1").Value >= Range("AE" & ThatRow).Value Then
                Range("AJ" & ThatRow).Formula = MValue
            End If

            If Range("N1").Value >= Range("AE" & ThatRow).Value Then
                Range("AK" & ThatRow).Formula = MValue
            End If

            If Range("O1").Value >= Range("AE" & ThatRow).Value Then
                Range("AL" & ThatRow).Formula = MValue
            End If

            If Range("P1").Value >= Range("AE" & ThatRow).Value Then
                Range("AM" & ThatRow).Formula = MValue
            End If

            If Range("Q1").Value >= Range("AE" & ThatRow).Value Then
                Range("AN" & ThatRow).Formula = MValue
            End If

            If Range("R1").Value >= Range("AE" & ThatRow).Value Then
                Range("AO" & ThatRow).Formula = MValue
            End If

            If Range("S1").Value >= Range("AE" & ThatRow).Value Then
                Range("AP" & ThatRow).Formula = MValue
            End If

            If Range("T1").Value >= Range("AE" & ThatRow).Value Then
                Range("AQ" & ThatRow).Formula = MValue
            End If

        ElseIf Range("AD" & ThatRow) = False Then
            Range("AF" & ThatRow).Value = ""
            Range("AG" & ThatRow).Value = ""
            Range("AH" & ThatRow).Value = ""
            Range("AI" & ThatRow).Value = ""
            Range("AJ" & ThatRow).Value = ""
            Range("AK" & ThatRow).Value = ""
            Range("AL" & ThatRow).Value = ""
            Range("AM" & ThatRow).Value = ""
            Range("AN" & ThatRow).Value = ""
            Range("AO" & ThatRow).Value = ""
            Range("AP" & ThatRow).Value = ""
            Range("AQ" & ThatRow).Value = ""

        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: you need a loop

Comment: Whenever you update a sheet from a Change event handler, it's a good idea to have `Application.EnableEvents` set to False, so you're not re-triggering the event with the changes you make.  Don't forget to set back to True when done.

Comment: you may also appreciate the use of [Select Case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement) over all those `If` blocks for code maintainability.

Comment: I'm relatively new to VBA and adapted this code from some that I found online. Would these changes help the code for the change event to work using the buttons?

Comment: Last year we used actual checkboxes and it ran well, but the check mark is preferred for this year's version.